# Knockout and timing of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a computed function that notifies a button if it should be disabled or not. 
I also have a subscribe to this computed function that updates an another observable. When this observable is updated, it runs a custom binding.

The problem is that the subscribe() is running before the button is disabled. I want the computed function to run first, then the button is enabled/disabled, and finally it runs the subscription..

Is this possible? setTimeout() is not a good option.

```
this.enableButton = ko.computed(function() { return true or false });
this.enableButton.subscribe(function() { myself.triggerBinding(true) });
```

html:

```
<button data-bind="enable: enableButton" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHgTS/1

```
var viewModel = {
    buttonIsEnabled : ko.observable(true)
};

viewModel.enableButton = ko.computed({
    read : function () {
        log("read enableButton");
        return this.buttonIsEnabled();
    },
    write : function (isEnabled) {
        log("write enableButton");
        this.buttonIsEnabled(isEnabled);         
    },
    owner : viewModel    
});

viewModel.otherObservable = ko.computed({
    read : function(){
        log("read otherObservable");
        return this.buttonIsEnabled();
    },
    write : function () {
        log("write otherObservable");
    },
    owner : viewModel
});

viewModel.otherObservable.subscribe(function(){
    log("run subscription");
    log("----------------");
});

function log(message){
    $("#log").append(message + "\n");
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```